# What makes silverlight object get loaded and its life cycle?

Tags: silverlight

I am new to Silverlight and web world. I am coming from Windows form world. I would like to know the basic steps involved in launching silverlight application. I have basic understanding and would like to confirm if my understanding is correct.
If a user does not have Silverlight installed and wants to run my silverlight appplication page, the first thing in the hosted pages, Silverlight.js will run and see if Silverlight is installed in the computer. (Just curious, where does it check?) if it is not installed, it will prompt you to install. Once installed, re launch the silverlight page. Since SL object is installed in the IE, IE will launch the Silverlight object in its 'sandbox', Silverlight in turn will look at the name of the XAP file it has to load and bring the xap file down to client and then based on the application manifest, it will start the main dll with app.xaml
Is this somewhat right? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it pretty much sorted.  A couple of refinements:

> Silverlight.js will run and see if Silverlight is installed in the computer. (Just curious, where does it check?)

The js attaches a startup routine to the window load event.  When the startup code runs then detects whether the `ActiveXObject` class is available (indicating an IE browser).  If this is the case it attempt to use that class to briefly create an instance of a silverlight object.  The result of this is used to determine if Silverlight is present.  On other browsers the `navigator.plugins` collection is used to determine if Silverlight is present.

> based on the application manifest, it will start the main dll with app.xaml

The manifest uses two attributes.  The `EntryPointType` specifies the intial class to instance, this is usually the app class (app.xaml is then loaded by into the class during construction by code auto-generated in the `InitialiseComponent` method), however it is possible to configure an alternative class to instance (just why you'd do that I don't know).  And `EntryPointAssembly` is simply the name of the assembly that the entry point type can be found in.